# Collection in entity framework model is not updating

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a couple of simple models. An PlaylistEntry model and a Playlist model which contains a collection of PlaylistEntry models.

Playlist:

```cs
    public class Playlist
    {
        private ICollection<PlaylistEntry> playlistEntries;

        public int PlaylistId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PlaylistEntry> PlaylistEntries
        {
            get => this.playlistEntries ?? (this.playlistEntries = new HashSet<PlaylistEntry>());
            set => this.playlistEntries = value;
        }
    }
```

PlaylistEntry

```cs
    public class PlaylistEntry
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PlaylistEntryId { get; set; }

        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Playlist")]
        public int PlaylistId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
    }
```

When I add a PlaylistEntry to a Playlist in a detached state, I expect that when I attach and save changes, the changes to the PlaylistEntries list will also be saved. They don't save and the list is empty.

Here's my code:

```cs
    var playlist = new Playlist { Name = "My first playlist" };
    using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext(stringBuilder))
    {
        context.Playlists.Add(playlist);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    playlist.PlaylistEntries.Add(new PlaylistEntry { FilePath = "lkdfj", PlaylistId = playlist.PlaylistId });

    using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext(stringBuilder))
    {
        context.Playlists.Attach(playlist);
        context.Entry(playlist).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext(stringBuilder))
    {
        context.Playlists.Include(x => x.PlaylistEntries).ToList();
    }
```

That last ToList call returns the playlist I create but the PlaylistEntries collection on it is empty.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong or suggest a different solution please? I've spent about 7 hours on this and can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: This is just a guess, but have you inspected the `Entry` for the `PlaylistEntry` object?

Comment: I'm wondering whether you need to attach those objects to `context.PlaylistEntries`, assuming that exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you're missing is how the Context Cache works.  When you attach an entity (either manually or by requesting an entity from the database) to the context, it's *watched* by entity framework for changes and tracking those changes.

You've added an object to an entitiy's propety, then added it to the context.  Entity Framework is now watching it for changes to do any additional work.  *All* objects added this way are marked as *unchanged*.  Marking the parent *changed* does not mark the *navigation properties* as *changed*.

You can either add the entity to the property inside the context:

```
using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Save PlayList 2 (in context add)");
    context.Playlists.Attach(playlist3);
    playlist3.PlaylistEntries.Add(new PlaylistEntry { 
      FilePath = "Entry3", 
      PlaylistId = playlist3.PlaylistId, PlaylistEntryId = 3 
    });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

... **OR** mark both objects entries after attaching the parent.

```
using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Save PlayList 2 (full attach)");
    context.Playlists.Attach(playlist2);
    context.Entry(playlist2).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.Entry(playlist2.PlaylistEntries.First()).State = EntityState.Added;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In both cases Entity Framework now knows what to do in the DB when `SaveChanges()` occurs.

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qE1TXx)

Comment: Thanks so much! Both solutions worked. I've decided to go with the first approach because it seems to make things much less complicated. For the second solution, I had to modify the code a bit to work with multiple new entries. Updated the post

Comment: For your first method, is there a way to get the PlaylistEntryId to auto generate? If I don't explicitly give an ID I get the exception `A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member 'PlaylistEntryId' of type 'MusicPlayer.Data.DAL.PlaylistEntry'.`

Comment: The answer to this is that my schema was outdated. I deleted and recreated the database which fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are calling `context.SaveChanges();` just after adding only `PlayList` without `PlaylistEntries`, Entity Framework sending the command to the database and resetting the context state. So after that adding `PlaylistEntries` to the `PlayList` would not make any effect. To insert `PlaylistEntries` with `Playlist` write your code as follows:

```
var playlist = new Playlist { Name = "My first playlist" };
using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext(stringBuilder))
{
    playlist.PlaylistEntries.Add(new PlaylistEntry { FilePath = "lkdfj", PlaylistId = playlist.PlaylistId }); // Even you don't need to specify `PlaylistId` here. EF can map it.
    context.Playlists.Add(playlist);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to add new entries to the list from within the context like the other answers have suggested. If anyone still wants to know how to get this working in a detached state, here's how:

```cs
var playlist = new Playlist { Name = "My first playlist" };

using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext(stringBuilder))
{
    context.Playlists.Add(playlist);
}

playlist.PlaylistEntries.Add(new PlaylistEntry { FilePath = "Song7" });
playlist.PlaylistEntries.Add(new PlaylistEntry { FilePath = "Song8" });

using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext(stringBuilder))
{
    context.Playlists.Add(playlist);
    context.Entry(playlist).State = EntityState.Modified;

    foreach (var entry in playlist.PlaylistEntries)
    {
        context.Entry(entry).State = entry.PlaylistEntryId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}

using (var context = new MusicPlayerContext(stringBuilder))
{
    context.Playlists.Include(x => x.PlaylistEntries).ToList();
}
```

The `context.Playlists.Add(playlist)` doesn't actually add a new playlist. From what I understand, it attaches the playlist and all of the new entries on it. If I don't use Add, I get an error because the PlaylistEntryID of the new entries are all set to 0 by default.